# Tried vcpkg install ffmpeg and found strange test.exe file is it a virus or not?

Tags: ffmpeg

04.03.2023 16:19:41;src\vcpkg\buildtrees\ffmpeg\x86-windows-rel\ffconf.LVKfbdVy\test.exe;test.exe;src\vcpkg\buildtrees\ffmpeg\x86-windows-rel\ffconf.LVKfbdVy;  VHO:Trojan-Downloader.Win32.Convagent.gen;;Microsoft® Incremental Linker;link.exe;Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86\link.exe;\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\Hostx64\x86;20240;

---

I think everything is in the title.
Is more like a  question to the ffmpeg team and opensrc resources where they hosted src or repo for the vspkg resources.
Or to the ms vcpkg team for how they check resources if its safe to download or not.

install vs2022 all. install vcpkg.
use command 'vcpkg install ffmpeg' result you got after some time file test.exe that most of antiviruses handled as trojan application.
see upper details; (path -vcpkg\buildtrees\ffmpeg\x86-windows-rel\ffconf.LVKfbdVy\test.exe;test.exe);
so questions is same:
is it real virus or not;
if not a virus ffmpeg or vcpkg give answer what that app doing;
if its a virus find the idiot who added it, and find the idiot who allowed it to be hosted.

best regards!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your question is, how would I put it, ever so slightly unclear. Please see the advice on [how to formulate a question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) so that it's clear and easy to answer. As you're new, it's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and go through Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to find out how these sites work. Then please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771878/edit) your question so that it makes sense. As it now is, it will be [deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-questions).

Comment: not sure what the body of your question even is, but `Trojan-Downloader` is never good

Comment: I think all in title; is more question to ffmpeg team and opensrc resources where they hosted src or repo for vspkg resources; or to ms vcpkg team how they check resources is safe to download or not; install vs2022 all; install vcpkg; use command 'vcpkg install ffmpeg' result you got after some time file test.exe that most of antivuses handeled as trojan application. see upper details; (path -vcpkg\buildtrees\ffmpeg\x86-windows-rel\ffconf.LVKfbdVy\test.exe;test.exe);

Comment: so questions is same: is it real virus or not; if not a virus ffmpeg or vcpkg give ansver what that app doing; if virus find who add it; and find who allow it to be hosted; best regards;

Comment: There's no point copy-pasting your question to a comment. When clarification is needed or you have new info to add, as advised previously please edit your question instead. No point putting it "all in the title" either; it just makes things more confusing. Rather go for "Is this a real virus" or thereabouts, then in the message body explain your situation.

Comment: not found edit because your site is bad design and now what  I see:

"
Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

    Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See the Help Center to learn more.
"

so if I had something to advice because had 30yeas windows expierence - not able to post....   ggg
looks like if will not resolve it will shift delete account and said goodby....
stackoverflow more adecvate in that cases....
fyi

Comment: We aren't the FFMPEG devs. We don't know where you downloaded this file. We don't know what they've packaged.

Answer (score 0):

This is a false positive. You need not worry.

Many “Linux-y” software projects use *autoconf*. These projects have a `configure` script. While the `configure` script is running, the C/C++ compiler may be called multiple times with “nonsense programs” to check for the presence/state of various features. That’s the `test.exe` you see. Because these programs are unusual (useless), virus scanners often flag them incorrectly, because their heuristics trigger.

Nevertheless, you should not compile software you do not trust on your computer. Even just compiling software is running arbitrary code.